# Plotting Name of States on Map using Node js and D3 in real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, redis

I have been trying to plot the names of the states on the map using Redis Pub/Sub system, Node js and D3.
Issue is that when I type in a state for first time on a Redis channel, it is plotted perfectly, but when I type in the second state, nothing happens. Since I am new to D3.js, am not able to figure out the problem.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
d3.json("india-states.json", function (json) {
    india.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('tags', function(data){
        console.log(data.message1);
        india.selectAll("text")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            console.log(data.message1 + "Second Time"); 
            var centroid = path.centroid(d);
            return "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + centroid[1] + ")"
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .text(function(d) {
            console.log("2");
            if (d.id == data.message1) {
                console.log("1");    
                return data.message1;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried exploring my code and found that it is correctly fetching the state name every time. But only in first attempt the state name goes forward after

```
console.log(data.message1);
```

In all other cases I get only one console output and that is the "console.log(data.message1);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable for the texts and move it outside `socket`:

```
d3.json("india-states.json", function (json) {
india.selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path);

var stateText = india.selectAll(".text")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter()
  .append("text");//variable outside socket

var socket = io();

socket.on('tags', function(data){

    stateText.attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        console.log(data.message1 + "Second Time"); 
        var centroid = path.centroid(d);
        return "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + centroid[1] + ")"
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style('fill', 'white')
      .text(function(d) {
        if (d.id == data.message1) {   
            return data.message1;
          }
      });
  });
});
```

If you want to keep track of your previous `message1`, you can create an array outside the function, and loop through it:

```
d3.json("india-states.json", function (json) {
india.selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path);

var stateText = india.selectAll(".text")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter()
  .append("text");

var arrayStates = [];//this array will hold all the names

var socket = io();

socket.on('tags', function(data){

    arrayStates.push(data.message1);//for each input, a new string

    stateText.attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var centroid = path.centroid(d);
        return "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + centroid[1] + ")"
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .text(function(d) {
        for(var i = 0; i < arrayStates.length; i++){
          if (d.id == arrayStates[i]) {   
            return arrayStates[i];
          }
        }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: console.log gives the same state name i published on the channel. But the thing is everything works fine for the first time. Whenever i type second state, only the first console.log at the start of sockets.on() works and no other output is seen in the console. So that means data is not able to go through the second time.                   I havent tried creating a variable for "text", will do it soon.

Comment: Why do you have `style("fill", "white")`?

Comment: Was just trying to change the color of text :-P

Comment: Hey, I tried your code of declaring a variable outside the socket block and it worked!!! Thanks :D Now the only thing remains is that whenever I enter the name of a state, the previously marked state name disappears and new one is displayed. How to keep the previous state of the map intact?

Comment: That's expected, because your "message" has only one state. You'll have to create a cumulative data, and then making a for loop to match all IDs. I'll edit the answer and show you how to do it.

Comment: By cumulative data you mean to provide it all the states at once and use for loop for marking?

Comment: No, I mean an array that has your previous input.

Comment: Ohh okay...so I should declare an array and store the data in it every time it arrives and then use 'for' loop to go through the array each and every time to display the names?

Comment: Exactly what i did...thanks Gerardo...it was a great help :) i might disturb you later though, if you dont mind :P

Comment: Hey I just needed a little bit more help. I have explained it in the first edit, if you can help me with it

Comment: Please, don't edit your questions once you have a perfect question/answer match. Just post another question.